# How to convert SASS to SCSS using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sass, converters

I need to convert many SASS (tabbed style) files to SCSS (curly bracket style) within a NodeJS+NPM+Gulp project on a regular basis. Note that I do not want to convert direct to CSS.

The purpose of this is so the SCSS code can be selectively refactored into another project by hand, as there are too many legacy constraints to import the SASS directly.

Ruby Sass has reached end of life, so I can't expect others to use sass-convert.

I know the newer Dart Sass converts to SCSS first internally, but I can't find any option to output this stage.

The solution needs to be easily contained within the NPM project. NodeJS is well outside my experience (I'm a python developer at heart) so writing my own converter from scratch, while possible, would be a significant undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sass-connvert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-convert) package. It can convert `css`, `sass` or `scss` to either `sass` or `scss`.

The usage is documented as follows:

```js
var vfs = require('vinyl-fs');
var converter = require('sass-convert');
 
vfs.src('./input/**/*.+(sass|scss|css)')
  .pipe(converter({
    from: 'sass',
    to: 'scss',
  }))
  .pipe(vfs.dest('./output'));
```